# Как залогиниться на сайт через Jsoup

Tags: java, post, jsoup

Здравствуйте.
Пытаюсь сделать регистрацию на сайте http://flymer.ru/signup  посредством Jsoup на Java

Результаты регистрации через браузер: 
[image: Результаты регистрации через браузер]

Что делаю я:

`Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("сайт.ру/signup")  .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").execute();`

```
             document = Jsoup.connect("сайт.ру/signup")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
                    .data("email", mail)
                    .data("pass", password)
                    .data("agree","1")
                    .cookies(loginForm.cookies()).
                     post();
```

И, естественно, ничего не происходит.
Судя по Form Data - нужно передавать еще и сторонние значения, и если fkey и skey мне удалось пропарсить и взять из html-странички, то как быть с остальными?
И откуда-то берется ts. 
Или я вообще не туда мыслю?

P.S. сайт.ру - из-за невозможности написать более одной ссылки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получил ответ на свой вопрос - без Headless browser это сделать невозможно.

Comment: Там какие-то скрипты выполняются?

Comment: Написал скрипт на питоне и попробовал авторизоваться -- работает http://pastebin.com/pFtZax0C и на указанное письмо отправляется подтверждение. Вам нужно повторить post запрос, передав в него данные с формы и должно прокатить

Comment: @gil9red , Да, там на страничке javascript обрабатывает запрос. И, кстати, такой же ответ я тоже получал, но логин\регистрация не проходила. У питона Javascript выполняется видимо при запросе, а у java нет

Comment: там нет никакого выполнения javascript, просто использование http, для регистрации скрипты у них не используются. Откройте у браузера панель разработчика, перейдите на вкладку сеть, выполните регистрацию и посмотрите какой запрос отправляет браузер и повторите его

Comment: @gil9red именно это я и сделал (скриншот в теме). Посмотрите на данные, которые передает форма - вы передаете их не все в вашем коде, но регистрация у вас проходит, у вас они автоматически видимо подставляются.   Robobrowser находится в списке Headless browser с поддержкой js, без которого, как я и сказал, здесь не обойтись

Comment: На том сайте подгружается js файлик, который обрабатывает события и подставляет значения, но он обфусцирован, поэтому, действительно проще воспользоваться Headless браузером, чем разбираться с спрятанным алгоритмом

Comment: @gil9red Но к сожалению, к андроиду Headless не прикрутить, спасибо за ответы